# I want to constrain what I can enter in forms for a relatively complex many-to-many relationship (more complex than in most examples)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

First of all: I'm using Access 2016

The basic setup I have is as follows:

- Customers (with name and business related information etc.)
- Contacts (contact information, each contact belongs to ONE customer)
- CustomerSite (address etc, each site belongs to ONE customer)
- Facilities (facility related information, each facility belongs to ONE CustomerSite)

These relations are implemented using a foreign key to a customer/site id. This works pretty well.

However, what I want in addition though is the following:

MANY of the Contacts can be responsible for MANY of the Sites and/or MANY of the Facilities.

Therefore I made the following junction tables:

- ContactsCustomerSite (foreign keys to Contact-ID and Site-ID)
- ContactsFacility (foreign keys to Contact-ID and Facility-ID)

[image]

This works as long as I carefully enter the data manually into the junction tables.

However, I want to offer forms to assign contacts to sites/facilities and this is where I have my problem.

So far I tried auto-generated forms with a little customization. They show e.g. facility information and then related contacts in a datasheet-subform (with links to a contact detail form).

The datasheets aren't properly constrained though. I can enter new contacts there but with several problems:

- The contacts I enter there become NEW contacts
- I have to manually select the customer to which the contact belongs, this is a source for errors (e.g. contacts of different customers could be entered as responsible)

I would like to select only from existing contacts that belong to the same customer.

How can I do this?

I don't really get what kind of form would be right to enter this, I also don't really understand what access does "below the surface" :(

Comment: Generally speaking you shouldn't have circular relationships, which is probably the root cause of your angst. I am however struggling to see how I would correct your relationships, but I think they should be more linear. I think your contacts maybe shouldn't be linked to a site, or more likely that the facility shouldn't be  linked to a contact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an unbound combo box to add new site and facility contacts.  Restrict the combo box to show only Contacts with a matching CustomerID.

For your Site form, use your current setup, but set the sub-datasheet to AllowAdditions = False.  Place an unbound Contact selection combo box on the form.  Place an [Add Contact] button next to the combo box.  When [Add Contact] is clicked, use VBA to create the record in the ContactsCustomerSite table.  Requery the sub-datasheet to display the new record.

Do the same thing on the Facility form.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to work quite well! I also had restrict the combo box to contacts that aren't already associated with the same Site/Facility.